# Android targetSdkVersion: accessing higher features, and risks

Tags: java, android, hardware-acceleration

I know how `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` work, but I need confirmation in this concrete case (I don't want to accidently overlook anything).

My app (game) supports all devices from Android 2.2 and above. Up to now, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`were set to 8 (i.e. API level 8, which corresponds to Android 2.2).

One of my `Views` works significantly smoother if hardware acceleration is turned on for it, but I can't set it in the project, because it requires **API level 11**. (How did I notice it then? One of my test devices offered a checkbox "force GPU mapping" in Developer Settings, so when I ran my app, I noticed the difference.)

I suppose the solution is to set `targetSdkVersion` to 11 (but keep the `minSdkVersion` at 8), and from code, check if we're running on API level 11 or above, and then enable HW acceleration for the View (Window). The last step is what requires the higher API level, because otherwise `FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` is not recognized in the source code.

Assuming all my code uses only `minSdkVersion` APIs (*except* when checking the platform version for exceptional calls at runtime, such as the hardware acceleration), is it guaranteed that there won't be issues on devices below `targetSdkVersion`? (Due to the above solution, I mean.) I would like to avoid that my app doesn't work properly on pre-Honeycomb devices. (Note that I test my app on a wide scale of devices in terms of platform versions, too, so testing is not a problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Activity`, use this line to set Hardware Acceleration for your window if it is API level 11 or higher:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.HONEYCOMB ) {
    getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
}
```

**EDIT**:
As an answer for your edit, Android Lint might throw an error saying it is not meant for the TargetSDK, but it will work and not throw any exception for older versions. If it does, the version is somehow > 10, and that cannot be possible.

But you should update your TargetSDK, because by using hardware acceleration, you are aiming for a higher API target.

Comment: I was about to do exactly this, but I thank you for the answer (and I'll set it as an answer if you can confirm me on the newly added question as well). Sorry for the delay (I had to edit my post).

Comment: What do you mean with `if you can confirm me on the newly added question as well`?

Comment: I edited my original post, see the last paragraph. I am asking if the approach with minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion (plus using the code you added, yes) is safe in all circumstances, i.e. on pre-Honeycomb devices as well.